# Loading a large image to a WPF app - Scrolling and Drawing both needed

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, scrollviewer

I have an idea of how to do only one of these req's, not both of them.

For loading a large image and be able to scroll to see all its parts, I added the image inside a `<ScrollViewer/>` and got what I needed.

For drawing on the image, I was able to load that image as the background of an `<Canvas/>`.

But how to accomplish both?

Basically, I have a very big image that I don't want to shrink, and that image has a bunch of rooms drawn on it (like a floor plan of a building). I have the coordinates of the rooms, and when a user clicks inside a room, I want to fill that room with color (currently i just have a listbox that says "Room 1 has been clicked").

Editted XAML (for shrinking image):

```
    <Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox x:Name="buildingCombo" Grid.Row="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboItemStyle}" Tag="{Binding}"
              Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"  Width="1000" SelectionChanged="buildingCombo_SelectionChanged"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">

        <ScrollViewer  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=floorPlanImage}" >
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <VisualBrush  >
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Stretch="None" x:Name="floorPlanImage" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
              x:Name="dataGridViewRoomQuery"  BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you need freehand drawing?

Comment: No, just fill a rectangle with a solid color programmatically

Comment: Then what do you want the `InkCanvas` for? I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe the InkCanvas is not what I need .. will Canvas do?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't fully understand what you need. Can you post a screenshot? if not here in StackOverflow, try `imgur.com`. Also, how are you currently determining that "room1 has been clicked" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just set the `Canvas` size to the Size of the `Image` that you have set as the `Background`, This will allow you to use the `ScrollViewer` and keep the correct `Image` size when set as the `Canvas` `Background`

Example:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}" >
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VisualBrush  >
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="/WpfApplication10;component/Capture.PNG"  />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that is very close to what I need. How do I avoid the image shrinking when the window gets resized? The image is part of a grid with a DataGrid on the bottom .. I thought Stretch="None" but that doesn't work.

Comment: The image will not shink at all, I think your Grid is setup incorrectly, are you able to show your Xaml for the Grid/DataGrid

Comment: I think its just this `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}"` it should be `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=floorPlanImage}"` otherwise your code works fine for me.

Comment: Ooops .. yup, typo. Thanks.

Comment: No problems :), Happy coding